Are Real Estate Agents / Homebuyers considered 'Telemarketers' when it comes to the Do Not Call list?
I have received numerous calls and texts over the past month asking to buy my house, some clearly from automated systems. Some (not all) of the callers/texters claim to be real estate agents. I am trying to understand if I have a private right of action against them under the TCPA, or any other recourse related to the Do-Not-Call list?
My confusion lies in that they are not trying to sell me anything--they are offering to buy something (house) from me. So (a) are they considered telemarketers for Do-Not-Call purposes, and (b) if I were to identify them, is there any reason I would not be successful in a small claims court if I sued them as described, for example, here?

Any particular jurisdiction?  I think "TCPA" implies United States, but it's not made clear.

The TCPA contains the following definition:

(5) The term “unsolicited advertisement” means any material advertising the commercial
availability or quality of any property, goods, or services which is transmitted to any
person without that person's prior express invitation or permission, in writing or
otherwise.

It doesn't specifically have to be trying to sell you something.  Advertising any commercial service, which includes real estate services, should be covered.
It's probably also likely that these calls are scams. Real estate agents don't buy homes, they act as brokers between sellers and buyers.
And even if they're legit, they receive a percentage of the purchase price as their commission. So they are indeed "selling" you something: when the purchase goes through, you pay them.

These do exist; they make money by cold-calling people with offers that sound good but really aren't because the person isn't trying to sell and doesn't know the true value of their own houses.

That sounds like the scammers I mentioned.

Cold-call real estate purchase isn't a scam because the person gets the full value of the deal (even if it isn't the fair market value of the property).

If they're deliberately low-balling the seller, because they know they can flip it for a profit, that's a scam.

@BarMar Not really, for it to be a scam, it would have to include some element of false advertising. It can be a scam if they tell you something provably untrue. If they - for example - tried to convince you your land is contaminated, or that if you don't sell quickly, the government is going to confiscate your home if you don't sell to hem. Otherwise they're just offering you a lowball offer. Nothing scammy about that. Scummy? Yup! Scammy, nope.

To me, trying to trick someone into accepting a bad deal is also a scam. If they imply that they're paying FMV, that's enough for me.

I expect they would try to discourage the person from getting an assessment, there will probably be lies tin there ("we've already evaluated it for you").
